# Mysql Distinct is not working with django ( am using windows 8)

Tags: mysql, django-models

```
role_type=ClientUserRole.objects.values_list('role_attribute', flat=True).distinct()
```

its giving duplicates also how can i get distinct role_attribute values..

Comment: What result do you expect? What result are you getting?

Comment: [u'Sales only', u'Job Administrator', u'Job Administrator', u'Job Worker', u'Job Worker', u'Job Worker', u'Sales only', u'Sales / events / emails', u'Sales / events / emails'] I am getting like this but i need distinct values like                                     [u'Sales only', u'Job Administrator', u'Job Worker', u'Sales / events / emails']